# scp from remote to local, where is my file?

Tags: windows, ssh, scp

I'm copying (or at least trying) a file from a remote server to my local pc (Windows) using the following command:

```
scp user@host:/usr/filename.txt /
```

It copies the file, but I have no idea where it is. What is the context of `/`? I tried several options for the last argument, like `/desktop` (which exists) or `/user/desktop` (which doesn't exist) but I can't find the file after the copy process anywhere...

Comment: You will find te file in the /,  ls /filename.txt

Comment: @mezgani: Sorry I forgot to mention I am on Windows locally. Not sure what `/` maps to?

Comment: The root directory  in Windows is c:\

Comment: @mezgani: The file is not there... Also `c:\Desktop` doesn't exist so I cannot be there...

Comment: Do you run the command on cygwin or in dos ?

Comment: Have you checked C:\Users\YourUsername ? (since you mentioned C:\Desktop doesn't exist, but /desktop works, but /user/desktop fails, so it may be you are at your home directory which is c:\Users\yourusername

Comment: @mezgani: in a CMD prompt. @Darius: no it wasn't there either, but it was indeed strange that `/user/desktop` failed explicitly. I downloaded winscp which made me copy the file.